# I need to know if it's possible how to get_the_tags to array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know if it's possible how to get_the_tags() to array?

i want to like this

```
$myarray  = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
```

i want use this code with "replace the_content" like this

```
<?php
function replace_content($content){
  foreach(get_the_tags() as $tag) {
    $out .= $tag->name .',';
    $csv_tags .= '"<a href="/' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>"';
  }
  $find  = array($out);
  $replace = array($csv_tags);
  $content = str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_content');
?>
```

find tag in content and replace with link

Answer (score 1):

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$my_array = array();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $my_array[] = $tag->name ; 
  }
```

.. and if your final goal is to output it like you wrote above then :

```
echo implode(',', $my_array);
```

.. and by the type of question , I was not sure if by one,two.. you might be meaning ID , so :

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$my_array = array();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $my_array[] = $tag->term_id ; 
  }
```

BTW - a quick look at the [`codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) would have shown you that ...

Comment: Ops Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/content/xxxxx on line 3

Comment: No, i want only $tag->name.

Comment: @user3006974 -If you  have a syntax error then just fix it . Copy & paste sometimes can get stray characters . This code works perfectly for me ( and the codex .. ) .

Comment: @user3006974 - I do not understand - Use the code where you need it .. for display use the implode part . ( but your question was for array.. if you just want to display them there other ways in wp ..)

Comment: i want use this code with "replace the_content"

like this

<?php
function replace_content($content){
  foreach(get_the_tags() as $tag) {
 $out .= $tag->name .',';
 $csv_tags .= '"<a href="/' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>"';
  }
  $find  = array($out);
  $replace = array($csv_tags);
  $content = str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_content');
?>

Comment: @user3006974 - Dude . The code I have posted works as per your Original question ( put `get_the_tags()` inside array ) . Please try to copy it again and try use it . You probably just copy and pasted wrong . For any other matter - please post a new question..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
// get all term names in an indexed array
$array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM wp_terms", ARRAY_N);
// walk over the array, use a anonymous function as callback
array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key) { $item = "'".$item[0]."'"; });
```

Notice that `anonymous functions` are only available since PHP 5.3

You should be able to do the same thing using `get_the_tags()` if you only want tags for a specific post:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
array_walk($tags, function(&$item, $key) { $item = "'".$item->name."'"; });
```

Judging from your updated question you don't need any of the above code, the only thing you need to to in order to get single quotes around each tag is:

```
foreach(get_the_tags() as $tag) {
  $out .= $tag->name . ',';
  $csv_tags .= '"<a href="/' . $tag->slug . '">' . "'".$tag->name."'" . '</a>"';
}
```

Comment: your result is > tag1,tag1
but i want like this > 'tag1', 'tag1'
how can i do this?

Comment: @user3006974 - Just wrap each tag in single quotes. I have updated the code.